# android retrofit2 response data, null how to fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I just posted a similar question on Stack Overflow and learned how to handle it with the body, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

If the return code is 0, I saw an article that it was connected to the server normally, but it was immediately terminated, and it is also said that it is because data is not entered normally.

Please advise me where the problem is

I confirmed that there is nothing wrong with the server side. Postman.

my retrofit2 class

```
private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(serverIp)
        .build()

    
    val userApi: UserAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI::class.java)
```

data class

```
data class LoginRequest(
    @SerializedName("userId") val userId: String?,
    @SerializedName("userName") val userName: String?,
    @SerializedName("password") val password: String?,
    @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String?,
    @SerializedName("gender") val gender: String?,
    @SerializedName("age") val age: Int?,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String?,
    @SerializedName("provider") val provider: String?,
    @SerializedName("pushNotiFl") val pushNotiFl: String?,
    @SerializedName("kakaoNotiFl") val kakaoNotiFl: String?,
    @SerializedName("deviceToken") val deviceToken: String?
)
```

user API

```
@POST("user")
    fun loginBody(
        @Body loginRequest : LoginRequest
    ) : Single<UserResponse>
```

user Model

```
fun loginBody(body: LoginRequest): Single<UserResponse>
```

userImpl

```
 override fun loginBody(body: LoginRequest): Single<UserResponse> {
        return RetrofitAPI.getInstance().userApi.loginBody(body)
    }
```

call ViewModel

```
fun loginEvent(userId: String?, userName: String?, password: String?, phone: String?, gender: String?, age: Int?,
                   email: String?, provider: String?, pushNotiFl:String?, kakaoNotiFl: String?, deviceToken: String?) {

        val test: LoginRequest = LoginRequest(userId, userName, password, phone, gender, age, email, provider, pushNotiFl, kakaoNotiFl, deviceToken)
        Timber.d("Test Checked ! $test")

        addDisposable(
            model.loginBody(test)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    _loginResult.postValue(it)
                }, {
                    Timber.d("response error, message : ${it.localizedMessage}")
                })
        )

    }
```

and my Activity

```
viewModel.loginResult.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
                if (it.status == 200){
                    Timber.d("Test Checked)
                }else{
                    Timber.d("Test Checked error ${it.status} ${it.responseData.login.userId}")
                }
            })
```

return code in logcat

[image]

postman

[image]

[image]

When checked in the activity, the response data is null error and status is 0. I'm not sure which is the problem....

First of all, if you see that the viewModel does not spit out the throwable, it is possible to communicate with the server, but it is thought that incorrect data was given

But it seems that the data was given normally, but I can't find where the error is due to this situation...

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a little tip

i added the log

```
2021-07-15 09:22:16.303 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST baseurl/user
2021-07-15 09:22:16.304 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2021-07-15 09:22:16.304 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 48
2021-07-15 09:22:16.306 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"age":24,"gender":"null","userId":"1801298504"}
2021-07-15 09:22:16.306 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (48-byte body)
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 baseurl/user (107ms)
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 00:22:17 GMT
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: keep-alive
2021-07-15 09:22:16.414 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Server: nginx/1.20.0
2021-07-15 09:22:16.415 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"userId":"1801298504","userName":null,"password":null,"phone":null,"gender":"null","age":24,"email":null,"provider":null,"roll":"ROLE_USER","regDate":null,"regId":null,"updDate":null,"updId":null,"pushNotiFl":null,"kakaoNotiFl":null,"useFl":"Y","deviceToken":null}
2021-07-15 09:22:16.415 21945-23596/com.project.glow I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (265-byte body)
```

The data I sent here looks like this
If it's true, it's strange that null values ​​don't appear here...

And there seems to be an error because the json data is not aligned. This part seems wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.
userId should come first, but it is last in logcat and the order is strange

I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"age":24,"gender":"null","userId":"1801298504"}

And it seems that the json order is wrong, so the response seems to be wrong. How can I fix this part?

I've asked several questions, googled enough, and I'm studying from the basics again. but i haven't solved this problem yet

Comment: I see in Postman there are some headers that are going along with the request. Are you sure you are sending all necessary headers too?

Comment: The header has never been touched I have added an image 
_che10

Comment: I would suggest you use OkHttp to print out the request body that is going from your end. Then we can figure out what is going and try to hit the same in Postman.

Comment: is the issue resolved or let me give my suggestion?

Comment: Ali Azaz Alam  // I haven't been able to solve it yet. I've been googling and trying to solve my problem, but I haven't been able to. If there is a solution, please help me please

Answer (score 0):

It was a response problem. The server did not send the value normally. According to the set rules.

thank you all

Comment: Ali Azaz Alam// yes it works perfectly. Ali Aziz Alam Thank you so much for your interest in me.

Comment: Hi, I have same problem . can you explain more about how to fix response? @Duseop