# how to fix retrofit2 return status 500, not server error?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

As you can see from the previous questions, I'm struggling with retrofit right now

As you can see from the title, I am sure it is not a server error because it is normally executed in post man.

Then, like last time, there is a high probability that it was my fault, but I was confused because I couldn't catch the error in this part.

I'm sorry to keep posting the same question, but I'm trying to get help again. I'm really sorry.

my post man

[image]

retrofitApi

```
private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(serverIp)
        .build()
val userApi: UserAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI::class.java)
```

userapi (controller)

```
@POST("user")
    fun loginBody(
        @Body loginRequest : JSONObject
    ) : Single<UserResponse>
```

userimpl

```
override fun loginBody(body: JSONObject): Single<UserResponse> {
        return RetrofitAPI.getInstance().userApi.loginBody(body)
    }
```

my viewModel ( call retrofit api )

```
fun loginEvent(userId: String?, userName: String?, password: String?, phone: String?, gender: String?, age: Int?,
                   email: String?, provider: String?, pushNotiFl:String?, kakaoNotiFl: String?, deviceToken: String?) {

        val jsonObject: JSONObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("userId", userId)
        jsonObject.put("userName", userName ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("password", password ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("phone", phone ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("age", age ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("email", email ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("provider", provider ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("pushNotiFl", pushNotiFl ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("kakaoNotiFl", kakaoNotiFl ?: JSONObject.NULL)
        jsonObject.put("deviceToken", deviceToken ?: JSONObject.NULL)

        addDisposable(
            model.loginBody(jsonObject)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    _loginResult.postValue(it)
                }, {
                    Timber.d("response error, message : ${it.localizedMessage}")
                })

        )

    }
```

my login Activity

```
viewModel.loginResult.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
                if (it.status == 200){
                    Timber.d("Test Checked ${it.responseData.login.age}")
                }else{
                    Timber.d("Test Checked error ${it.status} ")
                }
            })
```

JsonObject parameter value in logcat

```
{"userId":"1801298504","userName":null,"password":null,"phone":null,"age":24,"email":null,"provider":null,"pushNotiFl":null,"kakaoNotiFl":null,"deviceToken":null}
```

my error in logcat

```
loginEvent: response error, message : HTTP 500
```

I googled enough about this problem, and I think it might be a server problem because of the error code, but postman seems to work normally, so I think the data I send is the problem.

Please understand that the code is dirty. I spent a lot of time and thought about this problem and went through several tests, so I didn't think about readability to speed it up.

Comment: I think that you need to get rid of `JSONObject`. That is not from Gson, which is what you are using in Retrofit for serialization (`GsonConverterFactory`). Create a `data class` that models the payload that you wish to send and use that in your Retrofit call. Beyond that, add the OkHttp logging interceptor, Flipper, or some other solution so you can see exactly what you are sending to the server.

Comment: commonsWare /
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356733/android-retrofit2-response-data-null-how-to-fix-it

I'll have to go back to my previous question, so I'll give you the link. If you have time, I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to debug you traffic from the phone.
The issue can be related that you forget to add some field or header in the request. I mean some small difference between request's body/header that you send from the app and via postman.

You can capture traffic via Fiddler/Charles and see the difference between raw request that you send from the app and from the postman.

Comment: I added a log using okhttp in my previous question and I haven't solved it yet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356733/android-retrofit2-response-data-null-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Are sure you are writing the correct server address?
also before "user" end point, you need to add "/" so make sure you did it right.